# Android OpenCV Color Blob Integreation

Tags: android, opencv, colors

I have an application and when I push a certain button, I want it to open the OpenCv Colour Blob Sample.

I am really struggling on how to do this. Is there any easy way to link the two projects?

Any help would be great!

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try ,

1. Install ColourBlop app on the same device.
2. send this intent from your message as follows,

   ```
   startActivity(new Intent(getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage("package name of ColourBlop app")));
   ```

Comment: Hi David, Thank you for the reply! should I put the StartActivity.....etc in my main activity, or where I want to call the colourblob project? Thank you for your help in advance

Comment: You can that anywhere, whenever you need to open the colourblob, call above method.

Comment: Hi David, I have tried this but to no avail. Can you provide some more in depth tutelage on how to use this?